# How to get data with expire date on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello guys i am making search form with voucher code.

I have done about the search with this code :

controller :

```
function voucher(){
    $voucher = $this->input->GET('voucher');
    $data['search'] = $this->Voucher_m->check_voucher($voucher);
    $this->load->view('/VENDOR/'.country_code.'/Voucher',$data);
}
```

and this is the model :

```
function check_voucher($voucher){
    $this->db->join("uhd_restaurant" , "uhd_voucher.restaurant_id = uhd_restaurant.restaurant_id");
    $this->db->where('voucher_code',$voucher);
    $query = $this->db->get('uhd_voucher');
    return $query->result();
}
```

this is my simple view for my search code :

```
<?php
if($search!=NULL){
    echo "voucher dapat di gunakan";
}else{
echo "vocher tidak dapat di gunakan";
```

}
?>

There is no problem on search form, and i can view it. The problem is, when i search the code voucher, but if the expiry date of the voucher has expired, the search form will echo "Sorry, your voucher has expired"

The expiry date of the voucher, i have set it on my database.
guys can u help me how to set the expire code?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in two ways

1) Mysql method:-

```
 SELECT DATEDIFF('2014-11-30','2014-11-29') AS DiffDate
```

2) php method:-

```
   $now = strtotime("2016-05-30"); // or your date as well
   $your_date = strtotime("2016-05-27");
   $datediff = $now - $your_date;
   $dateDiff = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
```

Use current date and database date here and put an if condition in the view file to check the remaining days.

You can also use datediff() function in the where clause like below:-

[MySQL DateDiff in Where clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783347/mysql-datediff-in-where-clause)

[MySql - get days remaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17780868/mysql-get-days-remaining)

Comment: $now is current date, because you need data where voucher has been expired.

Comment: hmm can u more explain what you trying to suggest? so how about the $your_date?

Comment: Here I am suggesting that need to find date diff in current date and expiry date in days. if days less than equal to zero this means voucher expired.

Comment: You can also use DATEDIFF() function in mysql also.

Comment: in my database, table, i have input the start date(useable) for the voucher code, and the expired date. should i use that 2 dates for the diffdate?. example :  start date = 2016-05-26 and the expire date is 2016-05-28

Comment: Yes you are on the right way expire date - start date

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112993/discussion-between-kelvin-halim-and-deepak-dholiyan).

Comment: Sorry, I am little busy

Comment: just add another where condition like  $this->db->where('voucher_code',$voucher);